# Is there any way to update zone in specific views using dnspython?

Tags: python, view, dns, bind, dnspython

Just like the title. I was struggling to work with that, but I couldn't find any way to make that work.
Is there anyone know how to do that. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this problem has been solved by changing the `match-clients` dynamically through `ssh` and then `rndc reload`. This make the remote server only access to the specific `view` in which you want to update the zone using dnspython.